# VB.NET Expression is a value and therefore cannot be the target of an assignment

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to write a code that solves quadratics using VB

why this is showing error:

> Error 1   Expression is a value and therefore cannot be the target of an
>   assignment

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Dim A, B, C As Integer

        Console.WriteLine("Quadratic Equation calculator")
        Console.WriteLine(" AX^2 + BX + C")
        Console.WriteLine("Enter A")
        Console.Read() = A
        Console.WriteLine("Enter B")
        Console.Read() = B
        Console.WriteLine("Enter C")
        Console.Read() = C

        'ax^2 + bx + c = 0
        'enter a,b and c
        'set ac as variable
        'set b as variable
        'find number that multiplies for ac and adds for b
        'put them in (X+ )(x+ )

    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: What do those words mean to you when you read them?  You are also pretty darn new to SO, please read [Ask] and take the [Tour]  The parts about writing a good title especially, telling us *where* the error is etc

Comment: I'm not familiar with VB but It seem you are trying assign A,B,C to values of Functions Console.Read (). Try set A = Console.Read ()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Console.Read() = A
```

So, Console.Read() is procedure that reads value from console and return it. So you can't assign anything to it. But! But you can assign the return value to something. In this case it's A or B or C.
The correct answer will be:

```
A = Console.Read()
```

And so on.

Answer (score 0):

Your assignments are backwards.  Here is a working example of your code where I fixed each assignment.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/By3K0I

Imports System

```
Public Module Module1
    Public Sub Main()
        Dim A, B, C As Integer

        Console.WriteLine("Quadratic Equation calculator")
        Console.WriteLine(" AX^2 + BX + C")
        Console.WriteLine("Enter A")
        a = console.readline()
        Console.WriteLine("Enter B")
        b = console.readline()
        Console.WriteLine("Enter C")
        c = console.readline()

        console.writeline(a)
        console.writeline(b)
        console.writeline(c)
    End Sub
End Module
```